# Different results for select and traverse?

Tags: orientdb

I'm experimenting with OrientDb with the sample vehicle history database and have executed these two SQL queries, which I (would have thought) would be identical. I am trying to find all of the females who sold a vehicle to a male.

```
SELECT expand(out('Bought').in('Sold')[gender="Female"]) FROM Person 
  WHERE gender = "Male" LIMIT = -1
```

This one returns 124 records.

While

```
SELECT FROM ( TRAVERSE in('Sold') FROM (   
  SELECT FROM ( TRAVERSE out('Bought') FROM ( 
    SELECT FROM Person WHERE gender = "Male")
  ) WHERE @class = "Transaction" )) 
WHERE @class = "Person" and gender = "Female" LIMIT = -1
```

Returns 117 records.

I was hoping someone could explain to me what the difference is?

Comment: TRAVERSE without any condition in WHILE doesn't get one level like you did with the SELECT. But I'd need your db to play with. Any chance to publish it online somewhere?

Comment: @Lvca it's the public `VehicleHistoryGraph` db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We resolved this on gitter, but for anyone else wondering - this happens because the second query will remove duplicates (because of the traverse) but the first one won't.

Answer (score 1):

@codemix is right, to have the same result use set() that excludes duplicated:

```
SELECT FROM (
  TRAVERSE in('Sold') FROM (   
    SELECT FROM (
      TRAVERSE set( out('Bought') ) FROM ( 
        SELECT FROM Person WHERE gender = "Male"
      )
    ) WHERE @class = "Transaction"
  )
) 
WHERE @class = "Person" and gender = "Female" LIMIT = -1
```

Comment: Actually, the traverse seems to auto de-duplicate. It seems that the first query is the one returning the additional results. So the set should be applied to it. Thanks for showing the set function!